# function or associated item not found in `std::vec::Vec<u8>` when using MaxEndodedLen

Tags: maxencodedlen, vec

I have a struct definition as follows

```rs
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
pub struct Songs {
    pub name: Vec<u8>,
    pub cast: Vec<u8>,
}
```

This gives me the error when compiling

```rs
26 |     pub name: Vec<u8>,
   |                  ^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `std::vec::Vec<u8>`

27 |     pub cast: Vec<u8>,
   |                          ^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: replace your `Vec<u8>` with `[u8; 20]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `#[pallet::unbounded]` to your `#[pallet::storage]` items.

And get rid of `MaxEncodedLen`.

!!ONLY IF IT IS NECESSARY TO BE UNBOUNDED!!

Comment: It has to be bounded , that's the issue I am facing

Comment: Then, you should use `BoundedVec`.